# Google app engine datastore transaction commit throws InterruptedException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Any ideas anyone?  We are using other frontend threads simultaneously so I wonder if that is somehow related.

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1038)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:275)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:41)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:110)
at org.gails.infrastructure.google.DatastoreGAE.commitTransaction(DatastoreGAE.java:261)
```

Also reported http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8873&thanks=8873&ts=1361788757

Answer (score 0):

"Current transaction" is thread local. If you do transactions in parallel threads, then be carefull when using `.getCurrentTransaction()`. See the docs for more info: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#beginTransaction()

Comment: Thanks but we are not using .getCurrentTransaction()